# how to create hyperlink in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am using following xml and want to display in HTML using xslt.

```
    <resultDetailsData>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>0</ID> 
      <type>RESULTSTATUS</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="status">NOSTATUS</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>1</ID> 
      <type>LEVEL</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">1</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>2</ID> 
      <type>RESULTTYPE</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="resultType">SCREENIMAGE</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>3</ID> 
      <label>Description</label> 
      <type>TEXT</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">SC</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>4</ID> 
      <type>LINK</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2013-03-25 111117-840.jpg</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>5</ID> 
      <type>SCREENSHOT</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2013-03-25 111117-840.jpg</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>6</ID> 
      <type>DURATION</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:long">711</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>7</ID> 
      <type>STEPDESCRIPTION</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">SC</value> 
    </itemProperties>
    <itemProperties>
      <ID>8</ID> 
      <type>RESULTDESCRIPTION</type> 
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Screen Capture - SC</value> 
    </itemProperties>
  </resultDetailsData>
```

I have to create hyperlink for the value of value tag **type** **RESULTDESCRIPTION**. i.e, "Screen Capture - SC" When I click this it should open the file whose value will come from value of tag **type** **LINK**. i.e., "2013-03-25 111117-840.jpg".

I am looking for xsl code for this. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/resultDetailsData">
        <a href="{itemProperties[type='LINK']/value}"><xsl:value-of select="itemProperties[type='RESULTDESCRIPTION']/value"/></a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**[Working example](http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbb)**